# How to deploy a custom virtual machine to Azure utilizing the new Resource Manager via PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

What are the PowerShell commands you need to deploy a local custom .vhd file to Azure and get a VM running utilizing the new Resource Manager format?

There are a lot of guides out there, but none of them are complete end-to-end, and all seem to be aimed towards "Classic" mode.

Answer (score 1):

The following PowerShell Script will:

1. Login.
2. Create a Resource Group.
3. Create a Storage Account.
4. Create a Storage Account Container.
5. Deploy a local VHD file to the created Storage Account / Container / etc.
6. Create a virtual networking device with a public IP & internal IP.
7. Create a VM that mounts the disk image updated, utilizing the network device.

```
#LOGIN
Login-AzureRmAccount

# Enable verbose output and stop on error
#$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

################## Upload Custom VM to Storage Account Details ##################################
Write-Host "The following is a list of available locations:"
((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace  Microsoft.Storage).ResourceTypes).Locations | Select-Object -unique
$locationName = Read-Host 'Which location do you want to create things at?'

Write-Host "The following is a list of available Subscriptions:"
Get-AzureRmSubscription | format-Table -Property SubscriptionName
$subscriptionName = Read-Host 'What is the subscription name you want?'

Write-Host "Getting the Subscription..."
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName $subscriptionName | Select-AzureRmSubscription

$resourceGroupName = Read-Host 'What do you want to call the Resource Group?'
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $locationName

$storageAccountName = Read-Host 'What do you want to call the storage account?'
Write-Host "Creating the Storage Account..."
New-AzureRmStorageAccount –StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -Location $locationName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Type "Standard_LRS"
$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName

$storageContainerName = Read-Host 'What do you want to call the storage container?'
Write-Host "Getting the Storage Container..."
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $storageContainerName

Write-Host "Getting the Container Endpoint URI..."
$containerURI = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $storageContainerName).CloudBlobContainer.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.AbsoluteUri

$localFileName = Read-Host 'What is the absolute local file path for the source .vhd file?'
$storageFileName = Read-Host 'What do you wan to name the destination file on the storage account? (NOTE: Do NOT include .vhd on the end)'

$osDiskUri = $containerUri + '/' + $storageFileName + '.vhd'
#Upload to URL specified, with container name at end of path, the local fle specified.
Add-AzureRmVhd -Destination $osDiskUri -LocalFilePath $localFileName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName


################## Create VM From Storage Account Details ##################################

$vmName = Read-Host 'What do you want to name the Virtual Machine?'

$vmSuffix = Get-Random -Minimum 10000 -Maximum 99999
$vmSize = 'Standard_D3'
$nicName = 'VM{0}-NIC' -f $vmSuffix
$ipName = 'VM{0}-IP' -f $vmSuffix
$domName = 'vm-from-customimage-powershell-{0}' -f $vmSuffix
$vnetName = $vmName + '_network'


# Create the VNET
Write-Verbose 'Creating Virtual Network'  
$vnetDef = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $locationName -Name $vnetName -AddressPrefix '10.0.0.0/16'
Write-Verbose 'Adding subnet to Virtual Network'  
$vnet = $vnetDef | Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'Subnet-1' -AddressPrefix '10.0.0.0/24' | Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork

# Create the PIP
Write-Verbose 'Creating Public IP'  
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $locationName -Name $ipName -DomainNameLabel $domName -AllocationMethod Dynamic
# Create the NIC
Write-Verbose 'Creating NIC'  
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $locationName -Name $nicName -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id 

# Specify the VM name and size
Write-Verbose 'Creating VM Config'  
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize 
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $storageFileName -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption Attach -Linux

Write-Verbose 'Creating VM...'  
$result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $locationName -VM $vm

if($result.Status -eq 'Succeeded') {  
    $result
    Write-Verbose ('VM named ''{0}'' is now ready')
} else {
    Write-Error 'Virtual machine was not created sucessfully.'
}
```